# Array of structs in lua?

Tags: lua, lua-table

Does lua support some way of c-style structs ?

I want to convert something like the following font bitmaps from c:

```
struct charmatrix { char c;  int line[5]; };
static charmatrix font[] =
{
  "1", {0x2, 0x6, 0x2, 0x2, 0x2},
  "2", {0xe, 0x1, 0x6, 0x8, 0xf},

  "a" , {0x0, 0x5, 0xb, 0xb, 0x5}

}

font[letter].line[x]
```

[edit] added more data to show non-numeric indices

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The raw idea of a struct is not present in Lua but tables serve a similar purpose.

Using tables:

```
local font = {
  ["1"] = {0x2, 0x6, 0x2, 0x2, 0x2},
  ["2"] = {0xe, 0x1, 0x6, 0x8, 0xf}
}
```

This can then be accessed `font[letter][x]` or `font.letter[x]`. Bear in mind that Lua arrays are not zero-indexed, so x starts at 1.

If you need a bit more *structure* then you could use a function to construct the table:

```
local function charmatrix(c, l1, l2, l3, l4, l5)
  return {[c] = { l1, l2, l3, l4, l5 }}
end

local font = {
  charmatrix("1", 0x2, 0x6, 0x2, 0x2, 0x2),
  charmatrix("2", 0xe, 0x1, 0x6, 0x8, 0xf),
}
```

but that might be overkill.

Edit: If you want to keep the `line` in the code you could construct a table like so:

```
local font = {
  ["1"] = { line = {0x2, 0x6, 0x2, 0x2, 0x2} },
  ["2"] = { line = {0xe, 0x1, 0x6, 0x8, 0xf} }
}
```

Accessed `font[letter].line[x]` or `font.letter.line[x]`.
Note that keys which are strings do not need quotes when being defined, aside from numeric strings which is why `line` is not surrounded by quotation marks wheras `"1"` and `"2"` are. (So you could access with code: `font[letter]["line"][x]`)

Comment: `"1" = ` is not valid lua syntax. you'll need to put `[]` around it.

Comment: I'm not sure why you're quoting `"1"` and `"2"`. `[1] = ..., [2] = ...` would be clearer. And in fact you don't have to specify the indices, just write `local font = { {0x2, 0x6, 0x2, 0x2, 0x2}, {0xe, 0x1, 0x6, 0x8, 0xf} }`

Comment: Note that `font.letter` will not work here as `letter` is `"1"` or `"2"`.

Comment: @Keith I do need the explicit indices, as they are not all numeric ... 0,1,2, ...a,b,c,...A,B,C

Comment: @MikeRedrobe: And `["1"] = ...` is semantically different from `[1] = ...`. For example, `{ [1] = "foo", ["1"] = "bar" }` gives you a table with two distinct key/value pairs. (There's some potential for confusion here.)

Comment: @KeithThompson He's quoting the indices because the first field of the struct is of "char", so you'd expect string-like keys there.